# $L$ is a finite set of lines in general position. Determine the number of discs inscribed in triangles enclosed by each triple of lines in $L$.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, solution-verification, contest-math, combinatorial-geometry

> Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a finite collection of lines in the plane in general position (no two lines in $\mathcal{L}$ are parallel and no three are concurrent). Consider the open circular discs inscribed in the triangles enclosed by each triple of lines in $\mathcal{L}$. Determine the number of such discs intersected by no line in $\mathcal{L}$, in terms of $|\mathcal{L}|$.

Let $n=|\mathcal{L}|$. We can think that all intersetions are vertices of a planar graph. We have $n-1$ vertices and so $n-2$ edges on each line. So we have $V ={n(n-1)\over 2}$ vertices and  $E = n(n-2)$ edges. So the number of bounded faces $F $ (which are all convex polygons) we get from Euler formula $$V - E +F = 1\implies F = {(n-1)(n-2)\over 2}$$
Now, we can always draw a circle in a convex polygon that touches 3 sides of it and does not intersect other side: among all triples of (extended) sides in given polygon take a circle with the smallest radius. So the number of circles is the same as $F $.

Edit: If some three sides determine excircle then we enlarge this circle with a homothety so that this enlarged circle does touch sides which determine new circle as incircle of a triangle.

Any idea?

Comment: If we draw a circle inside a convex polygon that touches $3$ sides of it and doesn't intersect the other sides, that circle is not necessarily *inscribed* in the triangle enclosed by the corresponding $3$ lines. It could be one of the excircles, instead.

Comment: It should be easy to draw yourself an example of that. Draw a triangle, draw an excircle, add a faraway line to make the region containing that excircle into a convex quadrilateral.

Comment: Some homothety should help here to enlarge smallest circle so it touches sides of a polygon which does form a triangle which contains that polygon. @MishaLavrov

Comment: I don't see the mapping of "in/ex circle of any set of 3 lines $\rightarrow$ circular disc", because all of the 4 circles could be intersected by some other line in $L$. Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: [Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3Aopen%2C%20OR%20content%3Acircular%2C%20OR%20content%3Adisks%2C%20OR%20content%3Ainscribed%2C%20OR%20content%3Atriangles&p=1) found [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h495633p2782749).