# Is $0$ a limit point of the set $\{\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}a_{j}e^{\frac{2\pi i j}{n}}:\text{ }a_{0},...,a_{n-1}\in \mathbb{Z} \}$

Tags: limits, complex-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

Set $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n \geq 2$ can $0$ be a limit point of the set $\{\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}a_{j}e^{\frac{2\pi i j}{n}}:\text{ }a_{0},...,a_{n-1}\in \mathbb{Z} \}$ in the complex plane ? For $n=2$ the answer is trivially no as $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ forms a lattice in $\mathbb{C}$. I conjecture that $\mathbb{Z}[e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}]$ forms a lattice in $\mathbb{C}$, if this conjecture is true then the answer to my question is False.

Comment: $0$ is not a limit point when $n=2,3,4,6,$ but for every other $n,$ every real number is a limit point of the set, and, indeed is a limit point of the subset of the real elements in the set.

Comment: Assume $n>6$. The set is closed under multiplication. And it contains the number $z=2-2\cos(2\pi/n)$. Here $0<z<1$ and $z^m\to0$ as $m\to\infty$. For $n=5$ you need a different choice of $z$ for a similar argument to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, at least if $n\neq 2,3,4,6$ every real number is a limit point.

Basically, if $\cos(2\pi k/n)$ is irrational, you only need $a_0,a_k,$ and $a_{n-k}$ non-zero, and $a_k=a_{n-k}.$

This is due to the theorem:

> If $\alpha$ is an irrational real number, then $\{n+m\alpha\mid n,m\in\mathbb Z\}$ is dense in $\mathbb R.$

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Say $n=5$. We'll have $a_2,a_3 = 0$, so we just want $a_1 e^{2\pi i \frac{1}{5}}+a_4 e^{2\pi i \frac{4}{5}}$ to be arbitrarily close to an integer. We'll take $a_1 = a_4$ so that the sum becomes $2a_1\cos(2\pi\frac{1}{5})$. Since $2\cos(2\pi \frac{1}{5})$ is irrational, there exist choices of $a_1 \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ making $a_12\cos(2\pi\frac{1}{5})$ as close to an integer as you wish.

Comment: If I could I would accept your answer too. Unfortunately, I can only accept one answer.

Comment: Hi, any idea for this one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4286142/l-is-a-finite-set-of-lines-in-general-position-determine-the-number-of-discs